# Blur the join of 2 borders of different colors?

Tags: css

I have a div with borders with different colors. The design that im working towards blends the point at which these 2 borders join. Can this be done with CSS?

```
<div class="panel">
  dfds
</div>

body {
  background: green;
}
.panel {
  margin: auto;
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  background: white;
  border-radius: 10px;
  padding: 10px;
  border-right: 6px solid #D7D7D7;
  border-bottom: 6px solid #B9B9B9;
  box-shadow: 4px 4px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2); 
}
```

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/XJEWqp

Below you can see the bottom right corner has a sharp diagonal join:

[image]

This is the same detail in the design that im creating:

[image]

Comment: I don't think CSS borders have much in the way of controlling that.  Maybe you could fudge it with a drop-shadow but I don't fancy your chances there either.  I expect your only real option is to use an image for your border.

Answer (score 1):

Howsabout this:

```css
body {
  background: green;
}
.panel {
  margin: auto;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background: white;
  border-radius: 10px;
  padding: 10px;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 4px 4px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2)
                    , inset -6px 0px 0 rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.5)
                    , inset 0px -6px 0 rgba(0, 0, 255, 0.5);
     -moz-box-shadow: 4px 4px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2)
                    , inset -6px 0px 0 rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.5)
                    , inset 0px -6px 0 rgba(0, 0, 255, 0.5);
          box-shadow: 4px 4px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2)
                    , inset -6px 0px 0 rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.5)
                    , inset 0px -6px 0 rgba(0, 0, 255, 0.5);
}
```

```html
<div class="panel">
  dfds
</div>
```

Used red and blue to highlight the overlapping

Answer (score 0):

You can use a border-image for this purpose.

```css
div {
  margin: 30px;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  background: #DDD;
  border: 10px solid transparent;
  -webkit-border-image: url('http://i.imgur.com/7qsGJvm.png') 30 30 round;
  -o-border-image: url(http://i.imgur.com/7qsGJvm.png'') 30 30 round;
  border-image: url('http://i.imgur.com/7qsGJvm.png') 30 30 round;
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```